# Grails: Excel exporting .xlsx style issues, error message when opening the file

Tags: java, excel, grails, groovy, apache-poi

I'm using [grails-excel-export](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails-excel-export/excel-export) plugin to export data into an Excel (in xlsx format), but I'm having issues when opening the file with Microsoft Office (no problems with OpenOffice).

When I open it, I get the message *"We found a problem with some of the content in 'exportedFile.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"*, same as this one:

[image]

I've already found out that the problem comes only when applying any kind of cellstyle to the workbook, in my case I'm to set bold the first row.

This is the code:

```
def exportToExcel(results, headers, properties, ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {

    WebXlsxExporter webXlsxExporter = new WebXlsxExporter()
    webXlsxExporter.setWorksheetName("Sheet")
    webXlsxExporter.with {
        fillHeader(headers)
        add(results, properties)
        save(outputStream)
    }

    def wb = webXlsxExporter.getWorkbook()
    def row = webXlsxExporter.getSheet().getRow(0)
    makeFirstRowBold(wb, row)

    wb.write(outputStream)
}

def makeFirstRowBold(Workbook wb, Row row) {
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle()
    Font font = wb.createFont()
    font.setBold(true) //Already tried with font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD)
    style.setFont(font)

    for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(style)
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using?

Comment: I'm using "Gradle: org.apache.poi.poi:3.12"

Comment: That's pretty ancient and with [a tonne of known bugs fixed since then](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.12), what happens when you upgrade to something recent?

Comment: Tried with 3.17 and 4.1.0, but same result.

Comment: You might be running out of cell styles - try creating the cell style once outside the loop, they are designed to be re-used

Comment: I finally came up with a solution, I think that writing twice to outputstream was somehow corrupting the file, so I just removed the "save(outputStream)" line and it seems to work fine. In any case, thank you for your help @Gagravarr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this happens to anyone else, turns out that writing twice to outputstream was somehow corrupting the file.

So, since we are already writing to the outputstream in this line:

```
wb.write(outputStream)
```

I removed this one:

```
save(outputStream)
```

And it seems to be working fine.